# Assign a class to a div inside *ngFor based on condition

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to assign a class to a div that is inside a *ngFor iteration, based on a method.

Below is my HTML code: -

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of totalData let j = index">
          <div>
            <a (click)="selectData(data)">
              <div [ngClass]="{selected : selectedCodeMethod(data)}">
                {{data.code}}
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
```

My Ts code:-

```
selectedCodeMethod(data){
   if(this.selectedCode.includes(data.code)){
             return true;
     }
             return false;
}

selectData(data){
    this.selectedCode.push(data.code);
}
```

Even if the selectedCodeMethod() changes the content of selectedCode array, the method inside ngClass doesn't reflect changes.

What changes do I need to make?

Comment: Does [class.selected]=" selectedCodeMethod(data)" make any difference?

Comment: @manish sharma not sure why it's not working for you. Here is a codesandbox (borrowed from Tai) with same setting - https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-pond-c35rw where it works.

Comment: @Antoniossss I am performing the same code as the asker in this. Also pushing items but it still works that's why I deleted my answer.

Comment: correct, removed.

Comment: @Antoniossss I tried [class.selected] and it worked, but as as Tal Ohana mentioned not to call function in Angular template, I used pipe to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling function in Angular template is discouraged since it is inefficient and can raise errors - [more about it in this article](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496).

Back to your question, you should create Angular `Pipe` to match your needs. In your scenario we need a pipe that accepts an `array` and an `element` and return `array.includes(element);`:

```
@Pipe({
  name: "includes"
})
export class IncludesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(array: T[], element: T): boolean {
    return array.includes(element);
  }
}
```

Next, in your component you need to use the pipe and pass additional arguments

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li
        *ngFor="let item of items"
        [ngClass]="{ selected: selectedItems | includes: item }"
      >
        Item {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  selectedItems = [1, 3];
}
```

Lastly, pipes are *pure*, meaning you need to make immutable updates:

```js
selectData(data){
    this.selectedCode = [ ...this.selectedCode, data.code ];
}
```

You can experiment with the code in [this Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-water-5kwjw?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:44-396)

Comment: Actually this will not work either In case of OP code as change detection wont pick up new array content and pipe will not be reevaluated. In other words - this works only on the initial interation. OP has to at least reassign `selectedItems`. Deleted answer was more accuare as the change detection was the culprit here.

Comment: @Antoniossss you are correct, I will update my answer to match